# Cerrar notificación Html5

Tags: html5, push-notification

Muy buenas, tengo una notificación que lanzo cuando el usuario está un tiempo sin actividad, me gustaría saber si esa notificación se puede cerrar por ejemplo cuando el usuario mueve el raton o presiona una tecla, esta es mi función.

```
function mostrarNotificacion(titulo,cuerpo,tiempo,tipoIcon) {  //Esta funcion muestra las notificaciones si previamente tenemos permiso

    opciones = {
        icon: "img/"+tipoIcon,
        body: cuerpo,
        noscreen: true, //Reactiva la pantalla para mostra notificaciones
    };

    if(Notification) { //Para verificar si el navegador es compatible

        if (Notification.permission == "granted"){
            var n = new Notification(titulo, opciones);
            setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), tiempo);
            n.noscreen
        }
        else if (Notification.permission == "denied"){
            alert("Has bloqueado las notificaciones");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Su navegador no soporta la API de Notificaciones :(');
     return;
    }

}
```

He intentado poner esta linea

```
n.onmouseover = function(){alert("hola");}; pero no funciona y no se me ocurre como hacerlo.
```

Imaginemos que tengo este body `<body onload= onkeypress="parar()" onclick="parar()" onmousemove="parar()" >` Como sería la función parar? Eso es lo que no se, que tendría que poner en la función parar para que la notificación desaparezca. Gracias

Esta es la llamada a la función.

```
mostrarNotificacion("Inactividad","Va a salir de  esta pagina por inactividad","15000","reloj.jpg");
```

Comment: Hola Lorenzo. ¿Qué has intentado? No veo en tu codigo el evento para raton o teclado para ocultarlo. Primero intentalo y muestranos los problemas o errores surgidos. Un saludo

Comment: Prueba a cerrar la notificación en el evento move del mouse en el tag body

Comment: @LorenzoMartín para ocultar la notificacion, tendremos que referenciar el elemento HTML , no?  Tiene `id`? Muestranos un ejemplo de tu codigo donde salga esa notificacion. Un saludo